# When clicking show image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is a jsfiddle file for reference.

Im trying to make it so that when you press a button (1,2,3,4) the image that relates shows on click and overlaps with images as you click more numbers. I tried ----

```
$('#showButton').click(function() {
    $('#img3').show();
    return false;
});
```

But it isn't working.

Is there a way to say when clicking this button show #img1 
and when clicking another button #img2 overlaps that image

Thank you so much!

HTML

```
<h1>Question here</h1>
<button onclick="picture()">1</button>
<button onclick="picture()">2</button>
<button onclick="picture()">3</button>
<button onclick="picture()">4</button>
<button onclick="picture()">5</button>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<h1>Question here</h1>
<button onclick="picture()">1</button>
<button onclick="picture()">2</button>
<button onclick="picture()">3</button>
<button onclick="picture()">4</button>
<button onclick="picture()">5</button>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<!-- ////images -->
<img src="line-01.png" id='img1'>
<img src="line-02.png" id='img2'>
<img src="line-03.png" id='img3'>
<img src="line-04.png" id='img4'>
<img src="line-05.png" id='img5'>
<img src="line-06.png" id='img6'>
<img src="line-07.png" id='img7'>
<img src="line-08.png" id='img8'>
<img src="line-09.png" id='img9'>
```

css

```
img {/*    display:none;*/
position:absolute;
width:200px;}
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle for reference
https://jsfiddle.net/z81upsd3/#&togetherjs=bdmtFcwhGC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the number corresponding to the picture to show for that button in the onclick of that button:

```
<button onclick="picture(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="picture(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="picture(3)">3</button>
```

Then for your function:

```
function picture(n) {
  $("#img"+n).show();
}
```

This is a naive way to approach this problem, but it will work for you. There are many other ways to solve this, but I think this is a good start for someone new to JS. This also may cause you some more bugs when you click a button that has already been clicked after clicking a different one, but I think you can solve that!

Comment: Thank you so much! I agree that it is not the best way to code this hopefully one day I will get there

Comment: @Cobaltlee It just takes practice. Everyone ends up looking at old code they've written and smacked themselves. Half the fun of this field is watching your own progress!